# What format should a queue's filter have in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I need information about ActiveMQ Artemis filters. I have reviewed the official documentation, but I cannot find an adequate explanation.
I may be missing something to review.

- What format should a queue's filter have?
- What element can be used in a message to filter (e.g. headers, properties, etc.)?

I would appreciate any examples or resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the "format" (i.e. syntax) [the filter documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/filter-expressions.html) states:

> Apache ActiveMQ Artemis provides a powerful filter language based on a subset of the SQL 92 expression syntax.
>
> It is the same as the syntax used for JMS selectors, but the predefined identifiers are different. For documentation on JMS selector syntax please the JMS javadoc for [javax.jms.Message](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html).

Specifically, see the whole **Message Selectors** section in the [aforementioned JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html) for a full description of the selector syntax.

There are a handful of special message attributes that can be used in filters along with any actual message property. As the documentation states:

> The following identifiers can be used in a core filter expressions to refer to attributes of the core message in an expression:
>
> - `AMQPriority`. To refer to the priority of a message. Message priorities are integers with valid values from `0 - 9`. `0` is the lowest priority and `9` is the highest. E.g. `AMQPriority = 3 AND animal = 'aardvark'`
> - `AMQExpiration`. To refer to the expiration time of a message. The value is a long integer.
> - `AMQDurable`. To refer to whether a message is durable or not. The value is a string with valid values: `DURABLE` or `NON_DURABLE`.
> - `AMQTimestamp`. The timestamp of when the message was created. The value is a long integer.
> - `AMQSize`. The size of a message in bytes. The value is an integer.
>
> Any other identifiers used in core filter expressions will be assumed to be properties of the message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Justin.
In this case, the property(seter by a library) is this: `_property_enqueue.topic` and for some reason, I can't set this filter to a queue, neihter form Admin Console nor the broker terminal.
I tried a simpler one like `myprop` and it did work. Why the previous one(`_property_enqueue.topic`) didn't?
Thanks and regards.

Comment: I found the [Message Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html) where says:
**...Property names must obey the rules for a message selector identifier....** and a little further down on the _Message Selectors_ secction there are some syntact rules. Are these the rules?

Comment: Yes, the **Message Selectors** section describes the selector syntax which is mirrored for core filters in ActiveMQ Artemis. I updated my answer to hopefully make this more clear.

Comment: Regarding your selector with `_property_enqueue.topic` you'll have to be more specific about exactly what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what you're actually observing.

Comment: I wanted to create a queue that would only receive messages that had that property. The problem was in the dot(`_property_enqueue.topic`), which is not among the valid characters of the filter syntax. Problem solved.